# PHP generated HTML not reacted to External Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

i've trying to generate a form of and when the form checked onClick() event shall enable the select option. Here is my php code :

```
function generateOption()
{   
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++)
{
    echo "<option value='".$x."'>".$x."</option>";
}
}

function generateForm($I_Id)
{
    switch($I_Id)
    {
    case "I0001":
    {
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='".$I_Id."' value='".$I_Id."' id='".$I_Id."' onClick='Enable(this,BT)' />";
        echo "Binding Tape</td><td>";
        echo "<select size='1' name='KuantitiMohon".$I_Id."' id='BT' disabled >";generateOption();echo "</select></td>";break;
    }
}
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
function Enable(checkB,idE)
{
if(checkB.checked==true)
{
    document.getElementById(idE).disabled=false;
}
else
    document.getElementById(idE).disabled=true;
}
```

I'm not very sure what's the problem, however, in my previous html code, i able to enable the option there and now become unable after i change to php.

Comment: I think you have kept javascript code in separate file. Are you loading your javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Enable(this,BT)
```

You are trying to pass the "object" BT but your intention is to pass the "string" id named BT. You need to add quotes around "BT" like so:

```
onClick=\"Enable(this,'BT')\"
```

You need to escape the quotes around the onclick so that PHP does not assume it to be the end of your string.

Comment: thx! i solved it by changing onclick='Enable(this,BT)' to onclick=Enable(this,'BT')

Comment: Although that will work it would not be considered as "valid HTML markup". It's upto you if you can live with it.